# Fecha por defecto en un input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datepicker

Tengo este fragmento de código que muestra un datepicker con el uso de Jquery

```js
$(function () {
        $('#orderDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        })
    })

    $("#orderDate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Me muestra el datepicker y me coje el valor , pero me lo pone en formato "MM-DD-YY" tal como muestro en la imagen y me gustaria que fuese en formato dd-mm-yy

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás utilizando jQuery UI debería funcionarte.

Si estás utilizando algún otro plugin deberías revisar su documentación.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo con jQuery UI funcionando:

```js
    $(function () {
        $('#orderDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
        $("#orderDate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="orderDate" type="text">
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 3):

Prueba con / en vez de -

```
$('#orderDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

Comment: perfecto , ahora si ya funciona. Muchas gracias